# Changing "doas" prompt

Tags: command-line, root, doas

How may I change my `doas` prompt? For example, to change `sudo` prompt you just run

```
export SUDO_PROMPT="Prompt: "
```

Is there an equivalent for `doas`?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the setenv option in `/etc/doas.conf`?

Comment: I didn't saw it anywhere, what should I change there? You can write as a answer too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OpenBSD [`doas(1)`](https://man.openbsd.org/doas.1) utility does not allow you to change its prompt in the same way that `sudo` does.  This is by design, to keep it as simple as possible (which is [why it was written in the first place](https://flak.tedunangst.com/post/doas)).

Comment: Oh, thank you! But I don’t really care about customizing UNIX so it’s no longer problem to me. But still, thank you!